# Ignore cache in IE when running through Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, internet-explorer, caching

I often use IE as my development browser because of its tight integration with Visual Studio.  However, every time I start a web project from Visual Studio, I am forced to open the IE dev tools (with <kbd>F12</kbd>) and reload the page in order to avoid using cached versions of my code.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to open IE with the dev tools already open?  Or to open IE with the cache already ignored?

Comment: Use Mozila Its best browser for debugging purpose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use Internet Explorer **only** when debugging with Visual Studio.  I changed my settings so that the cookies and cache clear every time I exit IE so I have no trouble when debugging.  Obviously, this is not very practical if you actually use IE for anything else, but I use Chrome exclusively for all other purposes so this solution works quite well for me.

1. Open your **Internet Options** and check the box that says **Delete browsing history on exit**

[image]

2. Next, go into your "Delete Browsing History" settings by clicking on the **Delete...** button under the *Browsing history* header on the *General* tab -or- by clicking on **Settings** icon --> **Safety** --> **Delete Browsing History**

[image]

3. Uncheck the box that says **Preserve Favorites website data**

[image]

Now, your cache and cookies will clear automatically when you exit Internet Explorer (and when you stop debugging since it closes the browser)

*Note:  The screenshots and instructions given are for Internet Explorer 11.  Instructions for other versions may vary.*

***--- EDIT ---***

To force IE to load a new file instead of loading it from cache, so you don't have to close the browser and reopen it there's two things you can do.

First - you can go into your **Browsing history Settings**

[image]

and select **Every time I visit the webpage** under *Check for newer versions of stored pages:*

[image]

***If*** IE decides to work like it's supposed to - then caching is basically disabled and will load a new version of your files every time you visit the page or reload a page.

Another option that I highly recommend and is compatible with all browsers, is to use versioning on your code references to force the page to reload the new file instead of using cache.  I use this consistently with every application so I don't get phone calls about something not working correctly after I make a change - just for me to tell them to clear their cache.

This is very simple to do, just add your references like this:

```
<script src="/scripts/application.js?v1.2.85"></script>
```

All you need to add is the `?v...` at the end of the file name.  The browser identifies this as a new version of the file and reloads it instead of using cache.  You do not need to actually rename the file, only change how it's referenced in your HTML page.  This works for both JavaScript files and StyleSheets.

If you want to get really fancy, you could generate a random unique identifier on the server-side and insert it to your references every time the page is loaded, so the most recent version will always be used.

Comment: This gets me most of the way - although I like being able to make changes to `js` or `css` files and just refresh the browser instead of restarting the project.  The browser still pulls from its cache in this scenario.

Comment: @NathanFriend - See edit.  Let me know if you need any more help :)

Comment: You can also use Ctrl + F5 often to clear your cache more quickly.

Comment: @eyegropram - the OP was looking for a consistent, automated solution so they wouldn't have to do things like press Ctrl + F5 every time they run their solution.  This is a one-time setup and the cache is automatically cleared.

Comment: Also, with Ctrl + F5, would you want to tell your clients that every time you put out a new release that they have to make sure to press this button combination to make sure they get the most up-to-date version of the files?  I wouldn't want to tell my clients this, as I'm sure they wouldn't respond very well to that type of a solution.

Comment: I agree with you.  That is why I didn't add an answer.  Just an alternate method.  If you are going to refresh the key combo mentioned adds zero time to the process.

Comment: I'd rather tell them that than read a post on how to go through the menus in IE.  We can't always treat clients like they are daft.

Comment: @eyegropram - That was for the OP's specific situation for development in Visual Studio.  The second part of the answer, about versioning your js and css files, requires no interaction from the clients

Comment: I hear what you are saying, but unless every single time a js file or css file is saved the version is updated also they too will cache.  The version addition is great for production release, but less helpful in development with minor tweaks and changes like incrementally moving a DOM element.  I'm not trying to combat your answer.  It was thorough and well documented.  I think it is the best answer aside from it being the only one.

Comment: At least in the environment I'm developing (SharePoint online) the ONLY option that works is "Always refresh from server" - because it adds the Cache-Control: no-cache header to each request, forcing all content to be delivered fresh each time, with no possibility of stale versions being delivered by intermediary content caching servers. I never use VS to debug client side stuff though, so it's not a problem to just leave a single IE session with that option turned on and do all my testing/debugging etc. with that.