# Visual Studio html/css alter issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, visual-studio-2012

I am having trouble with Visual studio. When I hit run to see the site, some changes I make to css do not change and some of the things I moved in html won't move in the display as well. Using jQuery to display and hide divs and when I create a new div to create an employee of the month tab, the div goes under the other divs like home menu and about instead of hiding them(before I put that div it worked and followed the proper jQuery syntax). If I change the background in the css it stays the same. A friend told me it could need to have the cache deleted but I am not sure. I use other programs to create websites not VS but school is requiring VS.

Comment: While you have the browser open try hitting Ctrl + F5 to clear the cache.  Also, a more robust description of IE's caching already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27782519/1432074

Answer (score 0):

VS probably has nothing to do with this. By default IE's cache settings are terrible. Click the gear -> select Internet Options -> General -> Browsing History -> Settings and set the first radio button to EVERY VISIT TO THE WEBPAGE. (It's on Automatically by default, and it doesn't do a very good job of figuring out when things change)

Even with this setting, you may need to add several HTML tags to get to be 100% reliable.

Or you can try a different browser...

**EDIT**

If this happens in multiple browsers, try adding the tags I list in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28863309/webpage-stopped-responding-to-external-css-changes/28863665#28863665) to your header. This should force the major browsers to not cache (I know it's a lot, but it works)

Comment: It is doing it in both IE and chrome